# How to change the import path of fontawesome with laravel 5.7

Tags: css, laravel, sass, font-awesome

First, I've done my search before post this question, the answer that I found didn't work for me.

I did exactly the steps of the answer [Laravel 5.7 + Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome)

So, I have my mix.js configuration

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I runed `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` and tried `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save-dev`

and my dependency in package.json is

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.7.2",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
    }
```

Then, I import the styles

```
// Font Awesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
```

and I complied with `npm run dev`

I referenced my CSS file `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">`

After all these steps, I've got the error 404

```
GET http://localhost/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?462806316fea535a6a57651bc2b000b0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

But, I do have the files...

[image]
[image]
So I think the path would be

```
localhost/project/public/fonts....
```

But I don't know how to change that, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205925/url-rewriting-generate-wrong-urls-in-compiled-css-file-in-laravel-application?rq=1)

Set the resource root in the `webpack.mix.js` using the following: `mix.setResourceRoot('../')`;

Just don't know why this fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the screen print of nodes_module folder? Also, was there a compilation error when building with webpack?

I have below in node_module directory and it works fine for me
[node module image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO72k.png)

And i am using below in app.sccs file

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Comment: I updated it, I thought it's the problem of the path, just have no idea to resolve